# Is it possible to use the ArcObjects Runtime SDK on a Windows Store Application (windows 8, 8.1)

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-runtime, windows-8, tablet

I'm looking to develop a simple windows 8 tablet application with arcobjects. Is it possible to use the ArcObjects Runtime SDK? If not, is there an ArcObjects SDK for Windows store Applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a separate API for making Windows Store Apps](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/windows-store/), I'd recommend looking into that. It appears impossible to use ArcObjects from a Win8 App Sandbox [because of some of its runtime restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and the limited subset of Win32 it allows.